# "cannot read spec file" trying to create uf2 file

Tags: freertos, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to create a uf2 file for a Raspberry Pi Pico for a swarm robot. I get:

> arm-none-eabi-gcc: fatal error: cannot read spec file 'nosys.specs': No such file or directory

I installed the SDK:

```
git clone -b master --recurse-submodules https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk.git
```

Installed the toolchain 13.2.0:

```
brew install cmake
brew tap ArmMbed/homebrew-formulae
brew install arm-none-eabi-gcc
```

Added export lines to .zshrc file:

```
export PICO_SDK_PATH="$HOME/pico-sdk"
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/arm-none-eabi-gcc/13.2.0/bin/:$PATH"
```

In project folder I ran `mkdir build && cd build`. I built using `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..`:

```
 Defaulting PICO_PLATFORM to rp2040 since not specified.
 Defaulting PICO platform compiler to pico_arm_gcc since not specified.
 -- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
 -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
 PICO compiler is pico_arm_gcc
 -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/Cellar/arm-none-eabi-gcc/13.2.0/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc - skipped
 -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/Cellar/arm-none-eabi-gcc/13.2.0/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++ - skipped
 -- Found assembler: /usr/local/Cellar/arm-none-eabi-gcc/13.2.0/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc
 -- Configuring done (2.6s)
 -- Generating done (0.3s)
 -- Build files have been written to: /Users/myname/SwarmCapstone/build
```

Files in /build generated:

```
CMakeCache.txt      Makefile            elf2uf2             generated           pioasm
CMakeFiles          cmake_install.cmake freertos            pico-sdk            swarm_capstone
```

From `make` I get:

```
[  0%] Building ASM object pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/CMakeFiles/bs2_default.dir/compile_time_choice.S.obj
[  1%] Linking ASM executable bs2_default.elf
arm-none-eabi-gcc: fatal error: cannot read spec file 'nosys.specs': No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/bs2_default.elf] Error 1
make[1]: *** [pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/CMakeFiles/bs2_default.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I inherited this from a student who was able to load it on a Raspberry Pi Pico, but I made changes.

Answer (score 5):

Switching to `gcc-arm-embedded` resolved this issue for me on Mac. I needed to run 2 commands to fully cleanup the old install first:

```
brew uninstall --force arm-none-eabi-gcc
brew uninstall --force arm-none-eabi-binutils
brew install gcc-arm-embedded
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this trouble as well...

Following advice from https://www.reddit.com/r/embedded/comments/v0ghcs/pi_pico_how_can_i_set_up_an_enviroment_to_program/ , I installed the official Arm pkg file and then did:

```
PATH=$PATH:/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/12.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin
export CROSS_COMPILE=/Applications/ArmGNUToolchain/12.3.rel1/arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi 
export ARCH=arm
```

then I deleted the whole of the build directory, recreated and reran `cmake ..` - then I was able to successfully run `make` on the example code and generate an elf output.

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac i swiched from arm-none-eabi-gcc to gcc-arm-embedded to solve the problem.

```
brew uninstall --force arm-none-eabi-gcc

brew install gcc-arm-embedded
```